# C# DataRow RowFilter return incorrect row count

Tags: c#, datarow

I have a windows service that is running every 1 minute to check on a device with the amount of transaction the device made.

The code works perfectly to check if device exist and also to check device name.

However , there is 1 part where number of Rows is checked but not making sense.

The amount of transaction is always the Total Transaction instead of per devices when the RowFilter is already correct.
Picture below is for reference where i am checking if my Variables are correct and indeed it is. 
[image]

I have tried different method on filtering the Rows in my datatable.

Attempt 1 :

```
int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in HRDT.Rows)
{
string temp = HRDT.Rows[i].Field<string>(HRDT.Columns.IndexOf("HRDevices"));
iDT.DefaultView.RowFilter = "serialno = " + temp;
i++;
}
```

Attempt 2 :

```
foreach (DataRow row in HRDT.Rows)
{

HRDevice = row["HRDevices"].ToString();
iDT.DefaultView.RowFilter = "serialno = " + HRDevice ;

}
iDT.DefaultView.RowFilter = "serialno = " + temp;
```

None of these gives the correct result. 
Result should be showing the total rows of by each Device , not the Total Rows of ALL Devices.

I believe i am wrong in my method of row filter and thus seek assistance.

Current full code :

```
iDT = Ingressds.Tables["ytlhpfprec"];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (DataRow row in HRDT.Rows)
            {

                HRDevice = row["HRDevices"].ToString();
                HRDName = row["HRDName"].ToString();
                string temp = HRDT.Rows[i].Field<string>(HRDT.Columns.IndexOf("HRDevices"));
                LMTF.LogMessageToFile("Device serial is : "+ HRDevice);

                try
                {
                    iDT.DefaultView.RowFilter = "serialno = " + HRDT.Rows[i].Field<string>(HRDT.Columns.IndexOf("HRDevices"));
                    LMTF.LogMessageToFile("Device serial is : "+ HRDevice + " And temp is " + temp);
                    int ipRows = iDT.Rows.Count;
                    string ipString = ipRows.ToString();
                    LMTF.LogMessageToFile(HRDName + " have " + ipString + " transaction.");
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    LMTF.LogMessageToFile("Error in getting Ingress transaction in Property  : " + HRDName + " " + ex.Message);
                }
                i++;
            }

            Ingressds.Dispose();
            Ingressds.Clear();
```

Comment: It should be : string ipString = i.ToString();

Comment: @jdweng but "i" is just my integer variable to determine which row for HRDT....

Comment: @jdweng why? `i` is just the index of the `HRDT.Rows` foreach.

Comment: yes... ```i``` is just an index for HRDT.Rows... i required the RowCount for each filtered Device in iDT

Comment: try `int ipRows = iDT.DefaultView.Table.Rows.Count;`?

Comment: @DavidZemens - 1 Moment sir. Will do this in 1 minute. As i need to wait 1 minute for each transaction check.

Comment: The original code is always giving the total number of rows : iDT.Rows.Count

Comment: We don't put solved in the question.  Accepting the answer is good enough.

Comment: @LarsTech because im getting downvotes for no reason. :( and i feel sad about that.. so maybe if i help a little by labeling it solved ,  i might get upvotes instead? :(

Comment: Don't worry about the downvotes.  They happen sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`DefaultView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.defaultview?view=netframework-4.8) is a *property* of the `iDT`, which returns a `DataView`. But you're not referring to *that* `DataView` instance, you're referring to the `iDT` instance. If you modify your code to work with view, then it may be more apparent. You can use `view.Count` to return the number of records in that `DataView`:

```
try
{
    DataView view = new DataView(iDT);
    view.RowFilter = "serialno = " + temp);
    LMTF.LogMessageToFile("Device serial is : "+ HRDevice + " And temp is " + temp);
    int ipRows = view.Count;
    string ipString = ipRows.ToString();
    LMTF.LogMessageToFile(HRDName + " have " + ipString + " transaction.");
}
```

Comment: Apparently we have to create a view for the datatable... This is new.. Thank you great sir. I will remember this.  In conclusion to the answer , a DataTable to be viewed requires a Viewer called a DataView. A Viewer then may be imposed with a RowFilter without affecting the Table directly. This is the same as SQL Table and SQL View Table. Since we already add a "RowFilter" into the view , then all we need to do left is to do view.Count.